# Array from shared service has output but returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

Component that returns an array from a shared service

```
export class QuestionsComponent implements OnInit {
_questions: any;
constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
  this._questions = this.apiService._dataArray

}
}
```

which output using

```
{{ this._questions | json}}
```

in html component

```
[
  [
    {
       "foo": "bar",
        ... so on
    }
  ]
]
```

but when output the array using console both returns undefined

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this._questions[0])
console.log(this._questions)
}
```

the array is collected when triggered by an event from another component

**OTHER COMPONENT:**

```
  <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="option.checked" (ngModelChange)="UpdateData()"/>
  UpdateData(){
    this.apiService.getFilters(this._filters);
  }
```

**API SERVICE**

```
 _dataArray: any[] = [];
 getFilters(object){
  this._dataArray.length = 0;
  this._dataArray.push(object);
}
```

Comment: This should not behave like this. Could you provide some more information

Comment: Put console log inside the constructor and see what happens. Also try with debugging in browser. Also try after a some timeout. In this way you may find a clue

Comment: same thing, actually the data is collected when an event occurs from another component see edited code

Answer (score 0):

That's because the code in your constructor executes before `ngOnInit`.Try this instead:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this._questions = this.apiService._dataArray
  console.log(this._questions[0])
  console.log(this._questions)
}
```

Comment: console.log(this._questions[0]) returns undefined while
  console.log(this._questions) returns nothing